# Unity3D Help - Shooting object in direction of player rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a third person sports game and I wish to shoot the ball straight forward from the player.

I have a working script for shooting the ball, however it is attached to the main camera so only shoots in the direction the camera is facing.

I would like to alter this code to attach it to the player instead of the camera.

PS: I am still very new to C#, I assume the problem is in the "camera.main.transform" section but I don't know the code to change it to player.

my code is below;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public float shootSpeed = 300;

    Transform cameraTransform;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraTransform = camera.main.transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {  
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            shootBullet();
        }
    }
    void shootBullet()
    {       
        //Get the Rigidbody that is attached to that instantiated bullet
        Rigidbody projectile = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        //Shoot the Bullet
        projectile.velocity = cameraTransform.forward * shootSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You currently do `GetComponent<Rigidbody>` on that object itself .. this makes no sense since it would fire away "yourself" instead of a bullet. You have to [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) a bullet and apply forces/velocity here. You kind of missed the instantiation.

Then simply attach this script to your player Object instead and use [`transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html). `transform` returns the `Transform` component of the GameObject this script is attached to.

```
public class ShootScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Hint: By making the prefab field Rigidbody you later can skip GetComponent
    public Rigidbody bulletPrefab;
    public float shootSpeed = 300;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            shootBullet();
        }
    }

    void shootBullet()
    {
        // Instantiate a new bullet at the players position and rotation
        // later you might want to add an offset here or 
        // use a dedicated spawn transform under the player
        var projectile = Instantiate (bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);

        //Shoot the Bullet in the forward direction of the player
        projectile.velocity = transform.forward * shootSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that is kind of working, it gave me an error saying that bullet doesn't exist in this context, did you mean it to be bulletPrefab? also, I am now getting this error: InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. and my player is flying off in a weird direction lol

Comment: Ah actually never mind, I figured it out, i had forgotten to re-add my bullet prefab :) thank you very much!